# Swift: Playing sound in tapGestureRecognizer that matches to view

Tags: ios, swift, foreach, uitapgesturerecognizer

In `forEach` method, I got an array of views (one view is a card with an image of an animal). And it's a card deck view and when swiping to left or right next card show up. So I would like to play a sound in `UITapgestureRecognize` that match to view.

Animal stock:

```
class AnimalsStock {

    var list = [Animal]()
    init() {

        let item =  Animal(name: "Bear", soundUrl: "Bear", imageName: "Bear")

        list.append(item)

        list.append(Animal(name: "Cat", soundUrl: "Cat", imageName: "Cat"))
        list.append(Animal(name: "Chicken", soundUrl: "Chicken", imageName: "Chicken"))
        list.append(Animal(name: "Cow", soundUrl: "Cow", imageName: "Cow"))
}
}
```

Main view controller

```
HomeController: UIViewController {
   func setupCards() {

        allAnimals.list.forEach { (animal) in   
            let cardView = CardView(frame: .zero)
            cardView.imageView.image = UIImage(named: animal.imageName)
            cardView.animalLabel.text = animal.name
            cardDeckView.addSubview(cardView)
            cardView.fillSuperview()
        }

    }
}
```

and file with UITapgestureRecognizer

```
 class CardView: UIView {

@objc fileprivate func tapCard(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Here, I would like to implement a method that plays a sound that matches to the image
        pulseCard()

    }
}
```

Play sound method:

```
var player : AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound(soundUrl: String) {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: soundUrl, withExtension: "mp3") else { return }
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
func stopSound() {
    if player != nil {
        player?.stop()
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I would like to play a sound when tapping on a card that matches to view and I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: How do you get the `animal`?

Comment: Are you asking in home controller?
`var allAnimals = AnimalsStock()`

Answer (score 0):

You could assign each `CardView` with a unique tag in your for-each loop by making it enumerate the items and then access your animals list with that tag/index to get the url.

Alternatively you can always make the `CardView` have an `Animal` property and just assign that, so the `CardView` just has to read out the animal it has been assigned.

Comment: Instead of using a for each loop you go through your array using .enumerated() (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated) and assign the tag using cardView.tag = index

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my problem is to check the view property in the recognizer and then we get selected card:

```
@objc fileprivate func tapCard(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer, for card: CardView) {
        if let cardView = recognizer.view as? CardView {
        playSound(soundUrl: cardView.animalLabel.text!)
        }
        pulseCard()
    }
```